# Will OpenXML ever split a single word into multiple xml elements within a .docx file?

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

I've noticed while parsing .docx using OpenXML that sentences will be broken up by a ton of run elements, formatting, proofing and other elements. E.g. "Hello world" will look like:

`Hello</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Arial\" w:hAnsi=\"Arial\" w:cs=\"Arial\"/><w:noProof/><w:sz w:val=\"20\"/></w:rPr> World"`

This makes it very tough to do string replacements.

My question is - will OpenXML every split a single word into multiple elements? E.g.

`He</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Arial\" w:hAnsi=\"Arial\" w:cs=\"Arial\"/><w:noProof/><w:sz w:val=\"20\"/></w:rPr>llo"`

Comment: .docx files are Word/Open Office documents, not plain XML. They contain formatting, font and other information. OpenXML doesn't add that information; whatever software produced the document did.

Comment: Ah good point. So if half the word was bold and the other half wasn't, there would likely be some Open XML elements in between that word

Comment: Yes, and if that half of the word was in a different font, there would be elements in there for that as well. None of that is added while parsing; it's added when the document is created.